# ASP.NET Static classes and asp.net sessions

Tags: asp.net, static-methods, static-classes

Would someone be kind enough to explain or point to article that explains how the scope of static classes and methods interact with the scope of a ASP.NET user session.

Here is the more specific situation which explains my question:

1. User A logs into a asp.net website.
2. While doing something user A uses a static method which initializes some data.
3. User B logs into the same asp.net website.
4. User B hits the same static method.

Is the data already initialized once user B hits it?

Also what if the asp.net session of user A expires before user B hits the website?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Static data lives as long as the process is running. It is attached to the type.

If the data that is initialized is in a static context, then when user B hits the method, it will already be initialized.

Sessions are not relevant here - only the process.

If the process gets recycled, then the data will have to be reinitialized.

Answer (score 5):

Check these posts: [Why does my ASP.Net static function's "context" crossover between user sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435068/why-does-my-asp-net-static-functions-context-crossover-between-user-sessions?rq=1)

[What is the scope of a Static Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284491/what-is-the-scope-of-a-static-class)

[C# Static variables - scope and persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986051/c-sharp-static-variables-scope-and-persistence)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173138(v=vs.100).aspx

**In short:**

Is the data already initialized once user B hits it?

Yes

Also what if the asp.net session of user A expires before user B hits the website?

User B will access data initialized by user A

> Static data is shared among the entire application domain of your
>   webapp. It's shared among all the threads serving requests in your
>   webapp, it's not bound to a session/thread/user in any way but to the
>   webapp as a whole.